# Folding Square Bracket

Tags: brackets

I am doing a DIY project and looking for a folding square bracket. I've searched online and only can find folding brackets for shelves or tables and it is not exactly how I want it. Here is a crude image of how I need it to work. Can someone point in the right direction of to what something like this is called?

[image]

Comment: Could you post a sample image of what you found? I am not sure what you are asking nor could I tell from your drawing. Or perhaps describe the project? Are you looking for a hinge of sorts?

Comment: @JeffCates please look at this video, FF to about 1:40.... https://youtu.be/2WAJejtzDCc I’m looking for a similar bracket but his one opens up as a triangle. I essentially have 2 pvc pipes which I will screw the bracket on both ends, if I pull one PVC pipe, the bracket would open up.

Comment: So image 1 is 2 pipes together, 2 is seperating them, 3 is seperated. You want a hinge that that "Pops-up". You want it to lock in position like the one in the video?  You could take one like the video and drill the pivot point out and mount each leg to the pipe. Not sure how much of a lateral movement it may make.

Comment: I am also looking for a bracket like this but for a different purpose, have you figured it out NuWin?